# why child component does not get rendered in react

Tags: reactjs

**my doubt is why child component LibrarySubChild  is not called, Instead it goes to infinite rendering**

my library component is fetching an JSON from local url which in then set the result

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

     import LibrarySubChild from './Library';

    class Library extends Component {

      state = {
            libraries: []

          };

          componentDidMount() {
            console.log("library componentDidMount method called");
            this.fetchData();
         }

         fetchData = () => {

           fetch('/library/get-all-library',{ mode: 'no-cors'})
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then((data) => {
             this.setState({ libraries: data })
             console.log(this.state.libraries)
           })
           .catch(console.log);

      };

         render() {
           console.log("library render method called");
           const arrLength=this.state.libraries.length;
           return (
             this.state.libraries.length>0 ?
             <LibrarySubChild libraries={this.state.libraries} /> : arrLength
         );
         }

    }

    export default Library;
```

below component is not rendered

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

 const LibrarySubChild = ({ libraries }) => {
   console.log("library sub child render method called");
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Contact List</h1>
          {libraries.map((library) => (
            <div key={library.libid}>

                <h5>{library.libName}</h5>


            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )
    };

    export default LibrarySubChild;
```

what is the best way to solve this issue

o/p from the console
library componentDidMount method called
library render method called
library componentDidMount method called
 (2) [{…}, {…}]     this is console output and it goes on for an infinite time

Comment: Please explain what you mean by infinite rendering

Comment: library componentDidMount method called
library render method called
library componentDidMount method called
 (2) [{…}, {…}]     this is console output and it goes on for an infinite time

Answer (score -1):

**return/render** executes *before* componentDidMount.
the state libraries value (the length of which determines whether LibrarySubChild ever gets rendered) is fetched *after* Library componentDidMount (as it should). This leads the child component to change after componentDidMount, specifically, an instance of an LibrarySubChild is created and *after* that, a new instance of Library *should be* created with the new LibrarySubChild.

The question is, why isn't LibrarySubChild ever getting rendered - rather than an infinite componentDidMount loop in Library?

Answer: Hinted at above, it's because (1) a **new instance of Library** with the libraries state value reset (in the constructor) to 0 is created rather than simply running componentDidMount once due to React's diffing algorithm (more below) and (2) the state libraries value, which determines what's rendered, is executed at the return/render stage of component lifecycle which necessarily does not have any value in state for libraries because of (1.) -  remount is because the root element of Library begins as a p tag and changes to LibrarySubChild being the root.

[image]

Put another way, notice that render is executed before componentDidMount in diagram above. Whenever Library is instantiated (or re-mounted), fetchData is executed, which changes libraries state to having > 0 elements, and in turn results in the root element change from a p tag to the LibrarySubChild, which as we know results in a re-mount, and then back to square one (there's the logic behind infinite Library loop and never calling/rendering LibrarySubChild - the question at hand).

Now...you may be thinking "componentDidMount runs only once for any component...Fetching data is always recommended to happen there, right...?"

Generally, sure --- but it's crucial to note React's diffing algorithm (or [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)) is the core of whether or any component will remount. So, when will a component will have to remount (thereby triggering componentDidMount)?:

**Whenever the root elements have different types**, React will tear down the old tree and build the new tree from scratch. Going from  to , or from  to , or from  to  - any of those will lead to a full rebuild.

Is root value of Library changing? Indeed, from a p tag to a more-than-p-tag LibrarySubChild component.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

 import LibrarySubChild from './Library';

 class Library extends Component {

 state = {
        libraries: []
      };
        //componentDidMount RUNS **AFTER RETURN/RENDER**
            componentDidMount() {

           //Infinitely loops because new instances repeatedly made
           //As React's diffing algorithm notes change in underlying 
           //root element types.

            console.log("library componentDidMount method called");
            this.fetchData();
         } 

        fetchData = () => {
         fetch('/library/get-all-library',{ mode: 'no-cors'})
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then((data) => {

          //Side note: Try not to mutate state directly, like below: 

Suggestion: this.setState({libraries [...this.state.libraries, data]})             

         this.setState({ libraries: data })
         console.log(this.state.libraries)
       })
       .catch(console.log);

   };

     render() {
       console.log("library render method called");
       const arrLength=this.state.libraries.length;
       return (
           this.state.libraries.length>0 ?
         <LibrarySubChild libraries={this.state.libraries} /> : 0
     );
   }
}

export default Library;
```

Good Luck,
Mo